# How should I understand the meaning of 'start' in this sentence in Virginia Woolf's Orlando?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm reading Virginia Woolf's Orlando, however in the first paragraph in Chaptet 1 I ran into this sentence

> Orlando's father, or perhaps his grandfather, had struck it from the shoulders of a vast Pagan who had started up under the moon in the barbarian fields of Africa.

See, I went to all the dicts (all the ones I can find) to see whether there is such a phrasal verb as 'start up' or not, but surely 'start up sth such as business' isn't logically comprehensible considering the context.

I am now wondering if this 'start' means 'a slight movement of body because you've been surprised or excited'.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your supposition that 'started up' means a slight movement is almost correct. In fact it means any sudden movement including standing suddenly to your full height. I haven't read Orlando but it sounds as though Orlando's ancestor had decapitated a large African who had jumped up in a threatening manner at night. This use of 'start up' is rare and quite archaic now but would have been perfectly normal in Woolfe's time.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry for this belated reply and thank you for your answer. Your understanding of the context as well as the text is perfectly correct.

Comment: Glad to be of assistence, Hewie.